# Can you verify that this aircraft is not a variant of the T-34 Mentor?

Tags: aircraft-identification

On [this page](https://www.catalinaconservancy.org/index.php?s=visit&p=airport_in_the_sky), near the bottom, the aircraft below is identified as a T-34. I'm wondering if that's correct, but before I contact them to point out a possible mislabeling, I'd like to find out what it is or is not.

[image]

UPDATE -- I sent en email to The Catalina Island Conservancy, and they have changed the image to correctly show it as a Nanchang CJ-6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a [CJ-6](https://www.tested.com/science/575889-imported-warbirds-appreciating-nanchang-cj-6/). Popular as an affordable "warbird" type of aircraft, without the rarity.

[Various other images of the CJ-6](https://www.airteamimages.com/search.php?srch_keyword=Nanchang%20CJ-6) that seem to match up to what you posted.

Comment: I would go with this answer; that’s no T-34

Comment: agree. The T-34 doesn't have a cranked wing or knee-type main gear, nor the radial engine or the very long canopy. but the rudder shape is similar...

Comment: Which itself is a Chinese copy of the Soviet Yak-52

Comment: @CarloFelicione "This is not the T-34 you are looking for."

Answer (score -2):

It is in fact a Yak-52, Soviet era trainer aircraft.
It indeed looks nothing like the T-34.

[See Wikipedia for more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakovlev_Yak-52)

Comment: I thought it was a Yakovlev of some sort at first glance, too. But it's certainly not a Yak-52: they have straight wings but this plane has gull wings.